# UIAlertController Button Action in Swift 3

Tags: ios, swift, button, uialertcontroller, uialertaction

I want to perform an action when I click a button of a UIAlertController, I found a lot of information about this but none of them was useful for me, the closer answer I got was in this site: http://nshipster.com/uialertcontroller/

And the code I implement is this:

```
func success(message: String) {
    let alertSuccess = UIAlertController(title: "Listo", message: message, preferredStyle: UIAlertControllerStyle.alert)
    let okAction = UIAlertAction (title: "OK", style: UIAlertActionStyle.cancel, handler: nil)
    alertSuccess.addAction(okAction)
}

func paymentConfirmation(message: String) {
    self.myAlert = UIAlertController(title: "Confirmación", message: message, preferredStyle: UIAlertControllerStyle.alert)
    let myServices = UIAlertAction (title: "Si", style: UIAlertActionStyle.default) { action in
        self.success(message: "Tu pago ha sido exitoso")
    }
    self.myAlert.addAction(myServices)

    let okAction = UIAlertAction (title: "No", style: UIAlertActionStyle.cancel, handler: nil)
    self.myAlert.addAction(okAction)

    self.present(self.myAlert, animated: true, completion: nil)
    return
}
```

At the paymentConfirmation function is where I have the button that I want to show a second UIALertController, the name of the button is (myServices), so I added the action I want to that button to perform and then I call the method in this block:

```
 self.paymentConfirmation(message: "¿Estás seguro que quieres comprar el siguiente paquete de internet?")
```

So, what the App should do is that when the user clicks on "Si" at the first button Alert it should appear a second Alert, but this is not happening, it doens't do anything, can somebody help me?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are missing the second `UIAlertController` presentation

```
func success(message: String) {
    let alertSuccess = UIAlertController(title: "Listo", message: message, preferredStyle: UIAlertControllerStyle.alert)
    let okAction = UIAlertAction (title: "OK", style: UIAlertActionStyle.cancel, handler: nil)
    alertSuccess.addAction(okAction)

   self.present(alertSuccess, animated: true, completion: nil)
}
```

Comment: Oh you're so right, that was a little mistake from me but even such kind of details can make anything works, lol. Thank you very much!

Comment: Your welcome @ZitaNoriegaEstrada I am glad to help you, happy coding and best regards